# lines from one label to another

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to recreate the following using tkinter:

[image: Enigma Emualator]

Getting the general layout isn't that hard (though I don't think I've done so overly efficiently). I've been looking through the tkinter documentation and I've yet to find a way ti draw a line (as in the image) between two labels. The machine may be randomly generated each time so I'm not able to do everything manually. Is there a way to code this in without knowing the position of each label but with anchors or something of the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a `Canvas` widget, which has methods for drawing lines and text. If each individual number on the left and right is a canvas item with a unique tag based on the number, it would be quite easy to draw a line between them.

For example, lets assume each text item has a tag that is the number plus the prefix "l" or "r" depending on if the number is on the left or right (eg: l1, r42, etc).

The bounding box of each tag will give you the coordinates for that item. We can them do a bit of math to get the left or right edge along with the vertical center, and use that information to draw the line.

For example:

```
def draw_line(canvas, n):
    ltag = "l{}".format(n)
    rtag = "r{}".format(n)

    lx0, ly0, lx1, ly1 = canvas.bbox(ltag)
    rx0, ry0, rx1, ry1 = canvas.bbox(rtag)

    ly = int((ly0+ly1)/2)
    ry = int((ry0+ry1)/2)

    tag = "line{}".format(n)
    canvas.create_line(lx1, ly, rx0, ry, fill="gray", tags=(tag,))
```